# Using argument matchers when stubbing a method call results in type error

Tags: flutter, mockito, argument-matching

This is my code:

```
class Foo {
  int bar(int x) => x;
}

class MockFoo extends Mock implements Foo {}

void main() {
  final foo = MockFoo();
  when(foo.bar(any)).thenReturn(42);
  print(foo.bar(7)); // prints 42
}
```

How come passing in `any`  as an argument matcher gives me this error:

```
The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)
```

Where are we supposed to use `any` then, if passing it into the method we are trying to stub just gives me an error.

I was expecting the argument matcher to work, as displayed in [these docs](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito#argument-matchers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think those docs were written before null-safety was a thing.  You could change your bar method to receive int? instead of int.

```
  int? bar(int? x) => x;
```

Or

```
int bar(int? x) => x ?? 0;
```